# Change color of the Y axis in React LineChart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I need to change the color of the Y axis in my LineChart. I know it can be solved by setting `display: true` for `x` in the chart options and targeting `grid`, but that adds a bunch of unnecessary vertical lines, and I only need the first one. Is there a way to achieve this? Link to the editor https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntdk3g?file=src%2FLineChart.js

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to target the Y axis this way

```
border: {
        color: "red"
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).